# Android In-App Billing list of available products

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Is it somehow possible to get a list of all available products from the Play Store?

What I want to do is to get all available items and then show them in a ListView. Whenever someone taps the ListView the right item is opened in Google Play Store.

Is that possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: Have you ever managed to find an answer? The answers provided here so far answer the question 'how to get the details of existing products, once you have their IDs'. The question is how to get the IDs.

Comment: I haven't actually :( But I would still be interested in an answer. Like you said right now it's still the problem how we can get the IDs of the products...

Comment: I starting to believe that this is not possible. I will try too look around a bit more.

Comment: Ok nice! Keep us updated if you find anything...

Comment: But you have accepted one of the answers. Perhaps you should undo this.

Comment: I'm afraid I only managed to work around a hack. If you give generic IDs to your products (eg. prod1, prod2, prod3 etc) you can pass a long list of IDs to the getSkuDetails method that includes IDs that do not exist necessarily. No error will be returned and the result will contain the products that exist.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41118738/3283790) post, this is now possible using the Google Play Developer API (a.k.a. `android-publisher`):

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

In particular, the [Inappproducts: list](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/list) API:

> List all the in-app products for an Android app, both subscriptions and managed in-app products.

Answer (score 1):

Third-paty apis and services are not reliable. There is no reliable and convenient way for production yet. You have to store it on your server in encrypted json data file for example, without any php/java/something, just static file.

OR you can guess item skus in your code and check even non-existing items: myitem_00-myitem_99 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Google Play Store Api](http://code.google.com/p/google-playstore-api/), or you can also look into this [Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).

But both of these are **unofficial**.

Comment: Android Market API is deprecated and the Google Play Store is PHP and not Java for my Andorid project...

Comment: @user754730 I'm afraid but you might have to make a php server which does the work for you and then by making http requests you can fetch the data from your server.

Comment: You can also use [droidmeter](https://droidmeter.com/api/v1/documentation). For that you dont have to maintain your server, you can just request droidmeter server to get data. **But** its not free.

Answer (score 0):

This url will show you what to do:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails

Comment: Sorry, I can't find how to get list of all available products without passing list of products_ids. It's impossible, is it?

Answer (score -2):

You have to do below things.

- establish the connection between your app and google play app.
- Get the list of products which is register in your google console.
- prapare arraylist that contains product's id name and put into Bundle
- code to get purchase
  `ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
  skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");
  skuList.add("gas");
  Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
  querySkus.putStringArrayList(“ITEM_ID_LIST”, skuList);`

  - finaly one methode is reday in google_play_app that we need to call
- `Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, 
  getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);`
- call the getSkuDetails method on the In-app Billing Version 3 API, and pass the method the In-app Billing API version (“3”), the package name of your calling app, the purchase type (“inapp”), and the Bundle is our response
- extract the bundle and get the product names and display it in ativity.

Comment: This answers the question 'how to get the details of existing products, once you have their IDs'. The question is how to get the IDs.

Comment: What is mService ?

Comment: This is not an answer for the user754730 question.