# Android How to get product list from GooglePlay console

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm developing Android In-app Billing in my product. I want to ask you about **how to get all products that I already registered by Google play console**.

It's sample code from Google play.

```
List additionalSkuList = new List();
additionalSkuList.add(SKU_APPLE);
additionalSkuList.add(SKU_BANANA);
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
```

but If I put additionalSkuList is nothing, It will return nothing.

I want to know all products that I registered in In-app Products of Google play console to make Views by using product's information in advance.

Anyone has same problem ? Anyone knows a way to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Well, not that I'm aware of.

Basically `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);` eventually calls to `getSkuDetails()` method straight from `InAppBillingService.aidl`

```
 /**
 * Provides details of a list of SKUs
 * Given a list of SKUs of a valid type in the skusBundle, this returns a bundle
 * with a list JSON strings containing the productId, price, title and description.
 * This API can be called with a maximum of 20 SKUs.
 * @param apiVersion billing API version that the Third-party is using
 * @param packageName the package name of the calling app
 * @param skusBundle bundle containing a StringArrayList of SKUs with key "ITEM_ID_LIST"
 * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
 *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
 *              failure as listed above.
 *         "DETAILS_LIST" with a StringArrayList containing purchase information
 *              in JSON format similar to:
 *              '{ "productId" : "exampleSku", "type" : "inapp", "price" : "$5.00",
 *                 "title : "Example Title", "description" : "This is an example description" }'
 */
Bundle getSkuDetails(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, in Bundle skusBundle);
```

If you specify no list in your `additionalSkuList`, then you will get nothing as returned result.

In short, you just have to know (and list) all SKUs, then put this list into the query.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer! yes I knew it after I tried already ~ There are no ways to get all products ..... anyway..

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible using the Google Play Developer API (a.k.a. `android-publisher`):

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

In particular, the [Inappproducts: list](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/list) API:

> List all the in-app products for an Android app, both subscriptions and managed in-app products.

Comment: and to authorize link: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

Comment: I guess it is possible, but there is no Android SDK for it. You'd have to put something together with retrofit or some such.

Comment: It is useful only for backend, not for calling it inside Android app